# When i reload my page again insert data from $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, html

When I reload my page again insert data from `$_POST`, I can't remove `$_POST` DATA and browser cookie.

```
if($_POST['submit']) {
    $title         = $_POST['title']; 
    $location      = $_POST['location']; 
    $description   = $_POST['description'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `room_list` (`id`, room`) VALUES (NULL, '0');";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    if($query){    // True  }
    else {   // False  } 

    unset($_POST[submit]); 
    unset($_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: after the insert statement use a `header('Location: samepage.php');` - that will ensure that if the page is reloaded without submitting the form manually that the form data does not get sent again

Comment: have you tried something like `header('Location: http://www.example.com/');` or maybe look into using ajax so you can submit the form data in the background without having to redirect the client to a different page or have the page reload for the sake of submitting the form data.

Comment: Possibly your server is protesting against your use of `mysql_*` functions...just kidding *(well sort of, don't use `mysql_` anymore, it's removed as of PHP7)*, you might think about redirect as suggested by others. I wouldn't try and mess with the global arrays directly like that.

Comment: There is one ` missing around: room` in your INSERT

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you ought to test that POST variables are available before attempting to assign them as variables, upgrade the code to use `mysqli` or `PDO` and to avoid the form being re-submitted one would commonly use the `header` function to redirect after some particular actions / form submission to avoid multiple inserts

```
if( isset( $_POST['submit'], $_POST['title'],$_POST['location'],$_POST['description'] ) ){

    /* why do these not get used? */
    $title         = $_POST['title']; 
    $location      = $_POST['location']; 
    $description   = $_POST['description'];

    /* Should use `mysqli` or `PDO` - the `mysql` api is deprecated */
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `room_list` (`id`, `room`) VALUES (NULL, '0');";
    $query = mysql_query( $sql );


    header( "Location: " . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . '?status='.$query );

}
```